# Stargate swap error

Tags: web3.py, web3-providers, swaps

I'm trying to swap calling stargate protocol function. But there is en undifined error when executing. Don't know where to find solution. Please help me

```
chain_id = 111
rpc = 'https://arb1.arbitrum.io/rpc'
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(rpc))
contract = w3.eth.contract(address=STARGATE_ROUTER_CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi= STARGATE_ROUTER_ABI)
def get_lz_fee() -> int:
    data = contract.functions.quoteLayerZeroFee(
        111,
        1,
        wallet,
        "0x",
        [
            0,
            0,
            "0x"
        ]
    ).call()

    print(f"l0 fee - {data[0]}")
    return data[0]


def swap():
    amount = w3.eth.get_balance(wallet) / 3
    print(amount)
    data1 = contract.functions.swap(
        111,
        13,
        13,
        wallet,
        int(amount),
        int(amount / 2),
        [0,  # extra gas, if calling smart contract
         0,  # amount of dust dropped in destination wallet
         "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001"  # destination wallet for dust
         ],
        wallet,
        "0x"
    ).build_transaction({
        'from': wallet,
        'value': get_lz_fee(),
        'gas': 5_000_000,
        'gasPrice': 135000000,
        'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(wallet)
    })


    signed = w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(data1, private_key = pk)
    hash = w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed.rawTransaction)
    tx_result = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(hash)

    # Transaction status verification
    # If status == 1: Swap success.
    if tx_result['status'] == 1:
        print("Success! TX:", w3.to_hex(hash))
        return True
    else:
        print("Error! TX:", w3.to_hex(hash))
        return False
```

swap()